# How edit a SQL query which get it from xml file

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, xml, dashboard

I have several .xml files with different model and all of them contain SQL query which is something like below one, and I need to run them in C#, but since this .xml file is belong to dashboard I need just some part of it to be in select for example just a,b,c,d if my query is select a,b,c,d,e,f,g from x

```
<Dashboard>
    <Title Visible="false" Text="Management Dashboard" />
    <DataSources>
        <SqlDataSource Name="Perfomr" >ComponentName="DataSource1">
            <Connection Name="ConnectionString" FromAppConfig="true" />
            <Query Type="CustomSqlQuery" Name="myquery">
                <Sql>select  a,b,c,d,e,f,g from x</Sql>
            </Query>
            <ConnectionOptions CloseConnection="true" />
        </SqlDataSource>
    </DataSources>
    <Parameters>
        <Parameter Name="SDate" Type="System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Value="2018-09-01T00:00:00" Description="Start Date" />
        <Parameter Name="EDate" Type="System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Description="End Date" />
    </Parameters>
    <Items>
        <Chart ComponentName="chartDashboardItem3" Name="2G CSSR" ShowCaption="false" ParentContainer="pageDashboardItem1" DataSource="DataSource1" DataMember="Global_All_Layer_Day">
            <DataItems>
                <Dimension DataMember="date_id" DateTimeGroupInterval="None" DefaultId="DataItem0" />
                <Dimension DataMember="a" DefaultId="DataItem1" />
                <Dimension DataMember="d" DateTimeGroupInterval="None" DefaultId="DataItem4" /> 
                <Dimension DataMember="a" DefaultId="DataItem5" />
                <Measure DataMember="b" DefaultId="DataItem2" />
                <Measure DataMember="c" DefaultId="DataItem6" />
            </DataItems>
 .....
```

Comment: You can use Visual Studios to edit the XML from menu : Project : Add New Items : Xml File.  Then paste the xml into the view.  Any error will show up like compiler errors in the Error List.

Answer (score 0):

```
           String filename = "Dashboard.xml";

            XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(filename);
            XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
            XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.Select("/Dashboard/DataSources/SqlDataSource/Query/Sql");

            while (nodes.MoveNext())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SQL Query : " + nodes.Current.InnerXml);
            }
```

Comment: its not what I'm looking for... I have several dashboard.xml containing different queries. what I need is a code to first: find the query and then Dimensions and Measures second: edit select query to just return Measures and Dimenstions not all record:
query: select a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h from x 
dimensions:a,d
measures:f,e
updated code would be like: select a,d,e,f from x